# popstate event on history api does not fire

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I have a simple code to test the history api of html5

Just some buttons

```
<button name="hey1" onClick="historytestone();">history test one</button>
<button name="hey2" onClick="historytesttwo();">history test two</button>
<button name="hey3" onClick="historytestthree();">history test three</button>
<button name="hey4" onClick="historytestfour();">history test four</button>
<button name="hey5" onClick="historytestfive();">history test five</button>
```

and my js is like

```
function historytestone(){
    history.pushState({page: "ross"}, "ross","ross.html");
}

function historytesttwo(){
    history.pushState({page: "monica"}, "monica","monica.html");
}

function historytestthree(){
    history.pushState({page: "chandler"}, "chandler","chandler.html");
}

function historytestfour(){
    history.pushState({page: "joy"}, "joy","joy.html");
}

function historytestfive(){
    history.pushState({page: "rachel"}, "rachel","rachel.html?a=1&b=2");
}

// this does not work    
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    alert("hello");
});

//nor this works
window.onpopstate=function(event){
  alert("hello");
}
```

When I try to listen for the `popstate` event, I get no alert and no errors on the console. No metter what syntax I use, I get nothing.

Sorry, but I cannot see what is wrong. Please explain.

**EDIT**

Here is my problem. 
This is my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/QB7hm/1/) and this is the demo I was based [here](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/).

Now, I believe that my code is a simplified version of the demo.

I have to click the "back" button of the browser in order to fire the `popstate` event (see the alerts). But the demo can fire the `popstate` event (change content) just by clicking the names.

Why this happens? Why I have to hit the back button and the demo does not, even tho is the same code? Thanks again

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: @TimVermaelen Vermaelen Google Chrome v. 34.0.1847.131

Comment: It's probably a loading issue on your end. It's working fine for me: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/LuzF3/)

Comment: @TimVermaelen You mean like `window.onload='pushState()'`? But, the point of history api is not to load the page. I based my code on this demo `http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/`, which is part of this `http://html5doctor.com/history-api/`

Comment: Since it's unclear from your code how you load the scripts, try to add it before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Nothing special. Just the html buttons and then the js part that contains just the functions

Comment: @TimVermaelen I just tried what you suggested. Still no luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53904/discussion-between-tim-vermaelen-and-slevin)

Answer (score 2):

based on the definition here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

> The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes. If
>   the history entry being activated was created by a call to
>   history.pushState() or was affected by a call to
>   history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a
>   copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState()
>   won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered
>   by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or
>   calling history.back() in JavaScript).
>
> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
>   Firefox doesn't.

if you see the source code of http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/ each time when you click a link it calls the `updateContent` function (which is also the event handler of popstate) then it calls pushState.